# Getting an element inside a directory using java.nio.file.Path's

Tags: java, file, io, java.nio.file

I am currently getting to grips with file management in Java. As far as i've read, java.nio.file.Path is the preferred way of doing so.

Say I want to copy the contents of oldDir to the, currently empty, newDir. Every time I copy a file, I need this loong line just to get the Path of newFile:

```java
Path newDir = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("new");
Path oldDir = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("old");
for (Path oldFile : oldDir) {
    Path newFile = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("new", oldFile.getFileName().toString()); // Why so complicated? :(
    Files.copy(oldFile, newFile);
}
```

Is there something like `newDir.getChild(oldFile.getFileName())` to do what I want, or is there really no shorter way of doing it?

Comment: `newDir.resolve(oldFile.getFileName())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things you can do to make the code simpler:

1. Use [`Path#of(String,String...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#of(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)) or [`Paths#get(String,String...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get(java.lang.String,java.lang.String...)) to create your `Path` instances. Both methods delegate to the default `FileSystem`. The former was added in Java 11 and is now the preferred approach.
2. Use [`Path#resolve(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Path.html#resolve(java.nio.file.Path)) to append a relative path to some absolute path.

But there's also an error in your code. You are iterating over `oldDir` which works because `Path` implements `Iterable<Path>`. *However*, that iterates over the names of the path, not the children of the path. In other words, this:

```java
Path path = Path.of("foo", "bar", "file.txt");
for (Path name : path) {
  System.out.println(name);
}
```

Will output:

```
foo
bar
file.txt
```

If you want to iterate over the children of a directory you need to use something like [`Files#list(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#list(java.nio.file.Path)) or [`Files#newDirectoryStream(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream(java.nio.file.Path)) (the latter has two overloads). Both those methods only return the immediate children of the directory. There are other methods available to recursively iterate a directory and its sub-directories; browse the `Files` documentation to see what's provided.

So your code should instead look something like:

```java
Path oldDir = Path.of(...);
Path newDir = Path.of(...);
try (DirectoryStream<Path> dirStream = Files.newDirectoryStream(oldDir)) {
  for (Path oldFile : dirStream) {
    Path newFile = newDir.resolve(oldFile.getFileName());
    Files.copy(oldFile, newFile);
  }
}
```